# Better output with dplyr -- breaking functions and results

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is a long-lasting question, but now I really to solve this puzzle. I'm using dplyr all the time and I think it is great to **summarise variables**. However, I'm trying to display a pivot table with partial success only. Dplyr always reports **one single row with all results**, what's annoying. I have to copy-paste the results to excel to organize everything...

I got the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879638/use-dplyrs-summarise-each-to-return-one-row-per-function) 
and it almost working.

This result
[image]

Should be like the following one:
[image]

Because I always report my results using this style
[image]

Use this code to get the same results:

```
library(tidyverse) 
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(group=c("american", "canadian"), 
                 iq=rnorm(n=50,mean=100,sd=15),
                 income=rnorm(n=50, mean=1500, sd=300),
                 math=rnorm(n=50, mean=5, sd=2))
ds %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(iq, income, math),funs(mean, sd)) %>%
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  rownames_to_column %>%
  separate(rowname, into = c("feature", "fun"), sep = "_")
```

To clarify, I've [tried this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877053/summarizing-data-in-cross-table-with-grouped-by-variable-in-columns), but spread works with only one summary (mean or sd, etc). Some people use gather(), but it's complicated to work with group_by and gather().

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't look fine to me.  The first row is `character` class

Comment: Try `ds %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_at(vars(iq, income, math),funs(mean, sd))  %>% gather(key, val, iq_mean:math_sd) %>% separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% unite(group, group, key2) %>% spread(group, val)`

Comment: Thanks, you are always helping me. I added a new image to clarify my question.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it.  In excel you can can have multiple column headers, but, in R, it is better to have a single column header to not having issues with the type of the column

Comment: Hey, your code worked !! There are some way to adapt your code to my old syntax ? I change the variables to test via function:
var_to_test <- c("iq", "income", "math")
ds %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(var_to_test),funs(mean, sd)) %>% 
  gather(key, val, var_to_test) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>%
  unite(group, group, key2) %>% 
  spread(group, val)

Comment: If the mean and sd are the column names, a row identification of mean and sd is not needed though (the squares showed in the post)

Comment: Actually, your previous code is working `ds %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_at(vars(iq, income, math),funs(mean, sd)) %>% gather(key, val, iq_mean:math_sd) %>% separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% unite(group, group, key2) %>% spread(group, val)` Thanks much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of transposing (`t`) and changing the class types, after the `summarise` step, do a `gather` to change it to 'long' format and then `spread` it back after doing some modifications with `separate` and `unite`

```
library(tidyverse)
ds %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(iq, income, math),funs(mean, sd)) %>% 
  gather(key, val, iq_mean:math_sd) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% 
  unite(group, group, key2) %>%
  spread(group, val)
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked. I started a new question using your code. If you could take a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380034/rename-special-character-symbols-from-all-variables-in-the-dataset